# Defining a class with only a header - Can't find nonexistent cpp

Tags: c++, templates, header

My goal is to create my own stack via my linked list that can work as a template for ints, strings, etc.  Below are my two significant files.

*Main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Stack<int>* myStack = new Stack<int>();
    myStack->add(5);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

*Stack.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Stack 
{
public:
    Stack()
    {}
    ~Stack()
    {}

    void add(const T& val);

    ....

private:
    LinkedList<T> myStack;
};

template<class T>
inline void Stack<T>::add(const T& val)
{
    myStack.newHead(val);
}

....
```

I originally put Stack's implementation into its own .cpp but I was having problems and it was recommended to me to define the member functions inline with the .h.  The strange thing is that whenever I run my Main.cpp I get this:

> "error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Stack.cpp': No such file or directory."

This is my first attempt at making a class without a .cpp - what have I overlooked?

Comment: `addTo` should be `add`? You seems don't have any code named as `addTo`.

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason to include the implementation in the header file do not do it. Since `Stack` is a class template you have a compelling reason. If you deleted the .cpp file but didn't remove it from the project you will get the `C1083` error.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the .cpp from the project, which cleared up that error.  I am now getting hit with two "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" issues in Main.obj.  One deals with the constructor it seems, mentioning "LinkedList<int>::LinkedList<int>(void)"; the other with the member function involved, "LinkedList<int>::newHead(int const &)".  Perhaps I just need to convert LinkedList to using a .h only to clear this up.

Comment: It runs like a charm!  Thanks a bunch, Captain Obvlious and kotlomoy.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "Stack.cpp" from project. It's in Solution Explorer.